# Creating a typing test, and i don't know how to check the text i write in textbox, and "compare" it with 100 word text

Tags: c#

I tried with arrays but something doesn't work.

my code: string[] _besede = new string[9];

```
        _besede[0] = "just";


        _besede[1] = "because";



        _besede[2] = "never";


        _besede[3] = "done";


        _besede[4] = "anything";


        _besede[5] = "wrong";


        _besede[6] = "which";


        _besede[7] = "she";


        _besede[8] = "year";


        string bes = _typing.Text.ToString();

        if (bes.ToString() == _besede[1]) 


        {
enter code here
            MessageBox.Show("I don't know why that other thing doesn't work=:");

        }
        MessageBox.Show(_besede[1]);
```

The best way would be if you type the word wrong, then the word in other text box that displays the text to write changes the color to red, and it doesn't let you continue to type until you type the word correctly.

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: `"something doesn't work"` - *What* doesn't work?  In what way is this failing?

Answer (score 0):

In C# you compare String with .equals()

```
if (bes.ToString() == _besede[1])
```

Should be:

```
if (bes.ToString().equals(_besede[1]))
```

The logic for changing the color to red and prevent further typing is up to you!

Comment: String overloads the == operator so in C# you can use == for string comparisons. In Java on the other hand you would need to use .equals(). So I don't think this answer is correct. And the equals method is .Equals() in C#, not .equals()

Comment: Thank you so much for this Johan, saved me some valuable time.